# Writing data.table's to Spark with sparklyr efficiently

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to upload large `data.table`'s into Spark using sparklyr as follows:

```
copy_to(sc, obj, "name_of_object")
```

where `sc` is a Spark connection and `obj` my object. After some digging, I found that writing tables to Spark is done as follows (in `spark_data_copy()`): a csv file is created on disk using the serializer `spark_serialize_csv_scala` which uses base R `write.table()`. After writing the file, R instructs Spark to read the csv.

I found this to be not very efficient for my use R seems to hang and there is only so much tuning one could do on the csv writing part of the task. Does an efficient way exist to put data already in R memory into Spark?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use data.table's `fwrite()` to write a csv and import that using `spark_read_csv()`. This gives two speed ups:

1. `fwrite` is a lot faster than `write.table()`
2. For some reason, also using `spark_read_csv()` is a lot faster, run like this the local Spark instance will use all cores (and maybe there are more differences). For me, on a 16 core machine that really helps.

If given time, I will make more precise measurements.